Dynamic Parameter API-Based Report Design?
I've been googling around trying to find a basic structure to do something in PowerBI and am failing miserably.
What I want: I'm working w/ an API that has a basic hierarchy of data and want to create drill throughs in a report.  The ideas is that we display all values of "Level_A" in a table, when a value for "Level_A" is selected, it will call the API to get all values for "Level_B" that apply to the selected "Level_A" value, and show them in a table.  Then when a "Level_B" value is selected, it will call the API to get all values for "Level_C" that apply to the selected "Level_B" value, and show them in a table.

Level_A
Level_B
Level_C

Even a basic overview of a design or what controls to add to the report to allow this is super appreciated.  Thank you!
